# Redis in node - express. How to scan keys without initializing a client

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I have the following scanner

```
const scan = promisify(redisClient1.scan).bind(redisClient1);

const scanAll = async (pattern) => {
    const found = [];
    let cursor = '0';

    do {
        const reply = await scan(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern);
        cursor = reply[0];
        found.push(...reply[1]);
    } while (cursor !== '0');

    return found;
};
```

But to use it i have to initialize redisClient1 every time

```
const redisClient1 = require('redis').createClient(config.redisPort, config.redisUrl, {
    no_ready_check: true,
    db: 1
});


redisClient1.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err);
});

redisClient1.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Redis pre/dev.');
});
```

Problem is, i need the scanAll function to have as parameters the redisPort and redisUrl (db is always 1)

So the client initialization should happen once the function received the parameters

Meaning it would look something like this

```
const scanAll = async (url, port) => {
        const found = [];
        let cursor = '0';
    
        do {
            const reply = await customScan(url+port;, cursor, 'Match', pattern)            
            cursor = reply[0];
            found.push(...reply[1]);
        } while (cursor !== '0');
    
        return found;
    };
```

How can i do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this

```
const createRedisClient = async (port, url) => {
    const redisClient = require('redis').createClient(config.redisPort, config.redisUrl, {
        no_ready_check: true,
        db: 1
    })
    return redisClient;
}

const scanAll = async (pattern) => {
    const redisClient = await createRedisClient('1111', 'server.com')
    const scan = promisify(redisClient.scan).bind(redisClient);
    const found = [];
    let cursor = '0';
    do {
        const reply = await scan(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern);
        cursor = reply[0];
        found.push(...reply[1]);
    } while (cursor !== '0');
    return found;
};


const serverInfo = async () => {
    const redisClient = await createRedisClient('1111', 'server.com')
    const info = promisify(redisClient.info).bind(redisClient);
    const reply = await info();
    return reply;
}
```